# Transition for stopping after lightspeed travel

Tags: after-effects, video-editor, transitions

I am working on a video where I zoom into space and jump to another scene. My perspective is to do something what Andrew Kramer did in Star Wars Title.

[image]

I took help from the following video to radial blur and zoom in with optics compensation.

Its all okay till the first adjustment layer. But the zoom out transition doesn't feel right.(It feels the stars are traveling backwards)

I am looking for similar kind of transition as in the link below but just without the light.